# Magento 2 : Not able to place order with Google Pay Using Braintree

Tags: magento2, braintree, googlepay

I am using magento 2.3.6 & i installed paypal-braintree plugin for integrating google pay payment method using composer. Payment method is successfully installed but while placing an order i am getting below error.
I dont know why i am getting this error and whats the issue exactly.

**Your request failed. Use a different payment method, or contact us. Learn more [OR-CCSEH-21]**

[image]

Comment: @quickshiftin, It might be possible you are use a dummy card or possible your card is not support international transaction.